# Android vs Java causing some confusion for me when creating methods

Tags: java, android

I was helping a friend on his Java homework today, and I guess I didn't realize there being a difference between plain Java and Java in Android. Quick write up of the program:

```
public class myClass{

    public static void Main (String[] args){
        doThis();
    }

    public void doThis(){
        System.out.println("Did this");
    }
}
```

But when running that, I got a complaint that I needed to make the doThis() method to be static. Why is that? When I develop some basic things in Android, I never have to use the static keyword.

*Note: This could stem from the fact that I'm intimidated by what static actually means.*

Comment: FYI....same principle applies for Android also, create a static method and try to call instance method from it ( I am not the downvoter)

Comment: At a simplistic level, you are not used to seeing `static` in your Android apps because the entry point of an app isn't `static`. In normal Java, the entry point of your program is `static`. If you lookup what the `static` keyword does, that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because `Main()` is static.

If `Main()` was an instance method, and you had called `Main()` on an instance of `myClass` (e.g., `new myClass`), then `doThis()` could also be an instance method. Or, if your static `Main()` created an instance of `myClass`, it could call `doThis()` on that instance.

> When I develop some basic things in Android, I never have to use the static keyword.

That is because your entry points in Android tend to be instance methods on components (e.g., `onCreate()` of an `Activity`.

Comment: Gotcha. Will definitely read up on static, but it's starting to make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A static method is a method that is not invoked on any Object instance. A non-static method belongs to an object, and needs an object instance in order to be invoked. It's thus not legal to call an instance method from static method, since the static method is not invoked on any object.

You need to instanciate an object to call an instance method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyClass object = new MyCLass();
    object.doThis();
}
public void doThis(){
    System.out.println("Did this");
}
```

Android code is Java code, and has exactly the same rule.

Read the [Java tutorial about instance and static members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need to rewrite it like so:

```
    public class MyClass{  //fixed camel casing, classes start with upper case
       public static void main (String[] args){  //fixed lettering
          MyClass mc = new MyClass();
          mc.doThis();
       }

    public void doThis(){
        System.out.println("Did this");
            }
    }
```

This is nothing special about the difference between Android and Java, both will fail.  The problem is you are trying to reference a non-static method from a static context, this could cause issues, as static indicates that the class does **not** need to be instantiated to invoke a function.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can be called without having an instance of the owning class, so therefore you can do:

```
myClass.doThis();
```

Since your doThis() method isn't static, you'd have to create an instance object like so:

```
myClass instance = new myClass();
instance.doThis();
```

The main() method that is calling your doThis() method is a static method, and an instance of myClass isn't required for it to be called. This means that any methods being called by your main method must be static, or called on an instance object (see 2nd example above).